# What's the difference between using Data Export Service and Export to Data Lake, regarding dataverse replication?

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, data-export, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven

I know Data Export Service has a SQL storage target where as Export to Data Lake is Gen2 but seeing that Dataverse (aka Common Data Service) is structured data, I can't see why you'd use Export to Data Lake option in Powerapps, as Gen2 is for un-structured and semi-structured data!

Am I missing something here? Could they both be used e.g. Gen2 to store images data?

Answer (score 0):

Data Export service is v1 used to replicate the Dynamics CRM online data to Azure SQL or Azure IaaS SQL server in near real time.

Export to Datalake is similar to v2, for the same replication purpose with new trick :) snapshot is advantage here.

There is a v3 coming, almost similar to v2 but additionally with Azure synapse linkage.

These are happening very fast and not sure how community is going to adapt.